# The set $W^{⊥⊥}$ in a Hermitian space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory, proof-explanation

> **Problem Statement:** Let $W$ be a subspace of a Hermitian space $V$. Prove that $W^{⊥⊥}=W$

I am trying to figure out a good strategy for this proof.

I know that:

1. $W$ is a subspace of $V$
2. $W^{⊥}=\{\mathbf{v}\in V\ \ |\ \ \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle=0\ \ \  \forall\mathbf{w}\in W\}$
3. $W^{⊥⊥}=\{\mathbf{v}'\in V\ \ |\ \ \langle \mathbf{v'}, \mathbf{w'}\rangle=0\ \ \  \forall\mathbf{w}'\in W^{⊥}\}$

It makes sense to me that the set of all vectors perpendicular to the vectors in $W$ are in $W^{⊥}$ and that the set of all vectors perpendicular to those in $W^{⊥}$ would indeed be $W$. Because we had to consider all vectors in $W$ to get $W^{⊥}$, so the only vectors perpendicular to $W^{⊥}$ would be $W$. I feel like I am just going in circles... any tips on how to approach this proof?

Edit: I also have the fact that $W$ being a $G$-invariant subspace implies that $W^{⊥}$ is $G$-invariant, and that $V=W\oplus W^{⊥}$. Are these facts useful for this proof? Like maybe show that $V=W^{⊥⊥}\oplus W^{⊥}$, which would imply that $W^{⊥⊥}=W$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W^{⊥⊥}$ contains $W$ is trivial by definition.

Equality follows from dimensionality since taking perp gives a new dimension of $n$ minus the old one.

This doesn't work in infinite dimensions but that's good because it's not true.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see how showing $W^{⊥⊥}$ containing $W$ is trivial now. I think I was mostly confused about how to show it doesn't contain any elements in $V\setminus W$. So we know $$dim(W)+dim(W^{⊥})=dim(V)$$. Then we have $$dim(W^{⊥⊥})+dim(W^{⊥})=[dim(V)-dim(W^{⊥})]+dim(W^{⊥})=dim(V)$$ thus, $$dim(W^{⊥⊥})+dim(W^{⊥})=dim(V)$$? Is this good enough to claim that $W^{⊥⊥}=W$ since they have the same dimension, and since $W$ is a subspace contained in  $W^{⊥⊥}=W$?

Comment: if a subspace contains another and they have the same dimension, they are equal. Proof: a basis for the smaller one must also be a basis for the bigger one.

Comment: Yes, because a subspace of a vector space that has the same dimension of the vector space will span the entire space. Awesome!

Comment: Is it enough to just claim that $W^{\perp\perp}\oplus W^{\perp} =V$ by the given theorem ($W\oplus W^{\perp} =V$) which would give the result of $\dim {W^{\perp\perp}}=\dim{W}$

Comment: no, you can have different subspaces adding to the same thing. this is easy to see even in R^2

Comment: Well I am confused how I would get $$dim W^{\perp\perp}=dim W - dim W^{\perp}$$ without that fact.